# TypeError: element in array field Category: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'>

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading the csv file using Pandas, it's a two column dataframe, and then I am trying to convert to the spark dataframe. The Code for this is:

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
sdf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df)
```

The dataframe:

```
print(df)
```

gives this :

```
    Name    Category
0   EDSJOBLIST apply at www.edsjoblist.com  ['biotechnology', 'clinical', 'diagnostic', 'd...
1   Power Direct Marketing  ['advertising', 'analytics', 'brand positionin...
2   CHA Hollywood Medical Center, L.P.  ['general medical and surgical hospital', 'hea...
3   JING JING GOURMET   [nan]
4   TRUE LIFE KINGDOM MINISTRIES    ['religious organization']
5   fasterproms ['microsoft .net']
6   STEREO ZONE ['accessory', 'audio', 'car audio', 'chrome', ...
7   SAN FRANCISCO NEUROLOGICAL SOCIETY  [nan]
8   Fl Advisors ['comprehensive financial planning', 'financia...
9   Fortunatus LLC  ['bottle', 'bottling', 'charitable', 'dna', 'f...
10  TREADS LLC  ['retail', 'wholesaling']
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Your pandas dataframe columns are having differnt types as the error suggests

Comment: It would be helpful if you [edit] your question and include the output of `print(df.dtypes)` and a small sample of your data.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spark can have difficulty dealing with `object` datatypes. A potential workaround is to convert everything to a string first:

```
sdf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df.astype(str))
```

One consequence of this is that everything, including `nan` will be converted to string. You will need to take care to properly handle these conversions and cast the columns to the appropriate type.

For instance, if you had a column `"colA"` with floating point values, you can use something like the following to convert the string `"nan"` to a `null`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when
sdf = sdf.withColumn("colA", when(col("colA") != "nan", col("colA").cast("float")))
```

Comment: thank you for the help. I did as you suggested, but now, I am getting this error:
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Yash\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\spark-912d2316-6f98-469a-8abb-f6f4f99b6060\\pyspark-4be513ad-a898-4a41-a911-be158ff813b5\\tmppqmxo4ou'

Comment: That looks completely unrelated to this issue. Did you try restarting your spark context?